# Solving limit without L'Hôpital (cuberoot)

Tags: limits

I want to calculate the following limit without  L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x-\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}.$$

I don't know how to get rid of cubic root.

Comment: Well, $x\to+\infty$ and $2-x^3\to-\infty$ hence $\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}\to-\infty$ and $x-\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}\to+\infty-(-\infty)=+\infty$. No need "to get rid" of anything here.

Comment: By the way, this is your third question with no context (out of three) and, at your request, you have been pointed one year ago to some explanations about what makes an acceptable question on this site. Do you not care?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with no context?

Comment: Are you going to replay the act you played one year ago à propos your previous question, pretending you do not know that you are violating the rules of the site? Sorry but this works only once...

Comment: Im not pretending.... Im going to see what you mean and read the rules.... Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: "Im not pretending." Oh, so you admit being perfectly aware that you are flouting the rules of the site.

Comment: And I am wondering, how is the answer you accepted, helping in any way to solve the question?

Comment: Look, man... Ok, you are right, but I wasn´t aware of it... I asked another question and it has the context, I think... Im sorry, geez...

Comment: Why not stop being sorry and start accepting answers that DO address your question? You are lucky, there is one on this page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to. Here $2-x^3\to-\infty$ so $\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}\to-\infty$
and $x-\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Nice observation. +1

Answer (score 3):

Just use the decomposition
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$
You get 
$$a-b = \frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2},$$
and now you can put $a = x$ and $b = (2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$

Answer (score 1):

write $$x-\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}=\sqrt[3]{x^3}-\sqrt[3]{2-x^3}$$ and use that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$